# Does healing spell work on dragons

Tags: clash-of-clans

I attacked a village and thought I could use my healer on the dragon in my cc (my friend donated it to me) but it did not work. Looks like healer only heals ground army. If I take healing spells, will they provide healing to dragons if some archer or wiz together are attacking on him or  not.  I only have 4 spell space, so I am thinking of taking two heals. I dont have rage yet.

Comment: If you're able to have a dragon donated to your clan castle, then you should absolutely upgrade your spell factory and unlock the rage spell. In fact, I'd argue that should be one of your top priorities right now.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, while a healer will only heal ground units, heal spells will effect both flying and ground units provided they are not being damaged by an inferno tower as infernos towers block healing effects.

[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Spell)

Answer (score 0):

It should heal your dragon even if something is attacking him.

Comment: Except an inferno tower